# Multiple testing (bonferroni?) with GLM

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, multiple-comparisons, ecology

Hi everyone: I scored four mutually-exclusive behaviors (e.g. feeding, brooding, standing, preening) on a number of observations of birds in two different treatments, and two different nesting attempts. I'd like to see if these behaviors differ between attempts, treatments or both. Behaviors were all scored as a percentage of total time, treatment and attempt are both factors with two levels each.

I can use a GLM to analyze behaviors e.g.

```
mod1 <- glm(feeding ~ treatment * attempt)
```

Which gives me something like this:

```
                   Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)        0.1177     0.5285 26.4473   0.223  0.82549   
treatmentW         1.3943     0.8726 26.8958   1.598  0.12176   
attempt              1.0762     0.2963 15.9821   3.632  0.00225 **
treatmentW:attempt  -1.4901     0.5409 17.6237  -2.755  0.01322 *
```

My question: Since I'm running a separate model for each behavior, what's the best way to deal with multiple comparisons? Throw the p-vals from all tests into a Bonferroni (Dunn)? Should I include only significant p values, (attempt and treatment:attempt in this example) or all the p values from all tests (treatment, attempt and treatment:attempt)? Should I instead do a bunch of chi-sq tests and then bonferroni them? Or ignore multiple comparisons and just forge ahead?

Comment: Just a side-note - if your response is a percentage of total time, you might want to consider specifying a family in your glm (e.g. "family = binomial") that is appropriate for proportions. If you don't specify family it will select "family = gaussian", which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Since there were multiple hypotheses being tested, multiple comparison correction sounds appropriate. You can use Bonferroni (and probably Dunn). And you include *all* p-values, not just significant ones.

Comment: Slight correction: you include all p-values that you were going to examine. If you know you aren't interested in a particular p-value, you don't include it. The tradeoff is that, if it has a significant p-value, even at the adjusted level, you don't get to call it significant unless you redo all of the multiple comparisons with an adjustment for one more comparison than before, which may result in some of your hypothesis tests failing to reject.